# Does WinAPI wide-string functions support characters that consist of more than one code point

Tags: windows, winapi, unicode, utf-16

Does WinAPI wide-string functions support characters that consist of more than one code point (so called surrogate pairs)?

Is there anything about it in the documentation?

Comment: You've got the terminology wrong. Surrogate pairs consist of two code **units** to encode a code point.

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN article, [Surrogates and Supplementary Characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374069(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> Note  Windows 2000 introduces support for basic input, output, and
>   simple sorting of supplementary characters. However, not all system
>   components are compatible with supplementary characters.

Obviously, we're a bit beyond Windows 2000.

My experience has been that Windows does in fact handle surrogate pairs quite well. I know that there were some bugs here and there, but it's been a while since I kept up with the issue.

Short answer: Windows supports surrogate pairs, but there are likely some bugs in odd corners.

Comment: As an example, I don't think the console can handle surrogate pairs.  Each character cell is represented by a single 16-bit value, presumably treated as UCS-2.  On the other side, the file system accepts any string of 16-bit code units (provided they don't contain any reserved characters) even if they aren't valid UTF-16, which can cause trouble if you convert a filename to UTF-8 and back.